# How do coordinate wise meta-learning optimizers update learner networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization, meta-learning

I was reading [Optimization as a model for few shot learning](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=rJY0-Kcll) and [Learning to learn by gradient descent by gradient descent](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.04474.pdf) as I noticed both papers use something they call

> coordinate wise optimzers

for what seems good reasons for efficiency. However, does that mean that their LSTM models are 1D vectors because they only output one coordinate at a time AND because they share parameters across coordinates too?

I guess my main clarification and worry is this:

In the paper they say they share parameters across coordinates. In particular what I am worried about is that forget and update gates take $theta_{t-1}$ as input and thus if there are many parameters then their matrices would be enormous. For example recall one of the forget/update gate equations:

$$ i^{<t>} =\sigma( W_I [\tilde \nabla^{<t>}, \mathcal L^{<t>}, \theta^{<t>}, i^{<t-1>} ] + b_I )$$
$$ f^{<t>} =\sigma( W_F [\tilde \nabla^{<t>}, \mathcal L^{<t>}, \theta^{<t>}, f^{<t-1>} ] + b_F )$$

Does that mean that for each forget and update gate get they actually only receive 1 single coordinate at a time? i.e. the equations should be (for coordinate j):

$$ i^{<t>}_j =\sigma( W_I [\tilde \nabla^{<t>}, \mathcal L^{<t>}_j, \theta^{<t>}_j, i^{<t-1>}_j ] + b_I )$$
$$ f^{<t>}_i =\sigma( W_F [\tilde \nabla^{<t>}_j, \mathcal L^{<t>}, \theta^{<t>}_j, f^{<t-1>}_j ] + b_F )$$

so when they write $theta_t$ in any part of the paper is it actually just a single number $\theta^{<t>}_j$ (i.e. a single coordinate)? is that correct?

---

cross-posted:

- reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/deeplearning/comments/fdlnd2/how_do_coordinate_wise_metalearning_optimizers/
- Quora: https://qr.ae/ppuuSi

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's coordinate wise. But the trick is that it can be made into a vectorized for as shown here in it's pytorch implementation (https://github.com/markdtw/meta-learning-lstm-pytorch/blob/master/metalearner.py).

The main this is to write it like this (as it's actually implemented):

$$ f^{<t>} = \sigma( W^F_{:,j}[ h^{<t>}_{lstm, j} , \theta^{<t-1>}_j, f^{<t-1>} ] + b^F_j )$$

$$ f^{<t>} = \sigma( W^F_{:,j}[ lstm(\nabla^{<t>}_j , \mathcal L_{j} )_j , \theta^{<t-1>}_j, f^{<t-1>}_j ] + b^F_j )$$

One can vectorize it as follows:

$$ f^{<t>} = \sigma( W^F[ lstm(\nabla^{<t>} , \mathcal L ) , \theta^{<t-1>}, f^{<t-1>} ] + b^F )$$

where $h^{<t>}_{lstm} = lstm(\nabla^{<t>})_j$ is of size $| \theta| \times h_{lstm}$ where $h_{lstm}$ is the size of the lstm in the first layer and $\theta^{<t>}, f^{<t>}$ are of size $|\theta| \times 1$. Note the concatenation makes sure that the $[ lstm(\nabla^{<t>} , \mathcal L ) , \theta^{<t-1>}, f^{<t-1>} ]$ is of size $h_{lstm} \times |\theta|$. That is the main trick and notice that $W^F$ is of size $h_{lstm} \times 1$ and thus the fully connected layer **not** explode in dimensionality which is crucial!

So the important matrix multiplication:

$$ W^F[ lstm(\nabla^{<t>} , \mathcal L ) , \theta^{<t-1>}, f^{<t-1>} ] $$

is $ ( 1 \times h_{lstm})\times (h_{lstm} \times |\theta|)$

where the lstm parameters is of size $( 1 \times h_{lstm})$ and does NOT include the # of parameters $|\theta|$ in it.

Also, adding the bias is trivial since pytorch just "copies" and adds it to every location automagically in GPU.